# Trying to incorporate RegEX with Excel exercise from "Automate the Boring Stuff with Python"

Tags: python, excel, regex, openpyxl

I am trying to modify the project code from Automate The boring stuff with python chapter 13 page 315 to incorporate regular expressions into the code. For my Excel sheet I have a list of sensor names that need the "Unit" column filled out appropriately (see image below for an example). I have updated the project code dictionary to incorporate the corresponding units to the _BattV, _ft_H20,etc. as the sensor name is structured XXX_123_BattV, where the XXX is the project code, 123 is the sensor number and _BattV is the suffix indicating what type of sensor it is. I would like to match the last chunk of each sensor name using RegEX so that the code will update each sensor with _BattV with 'volts' in the unit column and so on.

Here is the code I have modified from the project example so far.

```
#! python3
#updateProduce.py - Corrects cost in produce sales spreadsheet.

import openpyxl

filename = 'stackoverflowexample.xlsx'
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
sheet = wb['stackoverflowexample']

#The produce types and their updated prices
UNIT_UPDATES = {
    '_BattV': 'volts',
    '_ft_H2O': 'Feet of H20',
    '_GWE': 'Elevation (ft)',
    '_PSI': 'PSI',
    '_TempC': 'deg C'}

#Loop through the rows and update the prices. 
for rowNum in range(2, sheet.max_row):  #skip the first row
    Sensor_name = sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=1).value 
    if Sensor_name in UNIT_UPDATES:
        sheet.cell(row=rowNum, column=2).value = UNIT_UPDATES[Sensor_name]

wb.save(f'updatedstackoverflowexample.xlsx')
```

Here is what I have gleaned from the RegEx section of the book:

```
import re

unitRegex = re.compile(r'_BattV|_ft_H2O|_GWE|_PSI|_TempC')

voltRegex = re.compile(r'.*_BattV')
fth20Regex = re.compile(r'.*_ft_H2O')
gweRegex = re.compile(r'.*_GWE')
psiRegex = re.compile(r'.*_PSI')
tempRegex = re.compile(r'.*_TempC')


mo = unitRegex.search('insert cell data here')
```

I am also curious if it is better to run the Regex and feed all of the matches into the dictionary first and then run the rest. Or if it is better to incorporate it within the for loop.

Finally here is the example screenshot:

Screenshot of excel spreadsheet showing structure of data:

[image: Screenshot of excel spreadsheet showing structure of data]

Comment: `*_ft_H2O` is not a regex, it is a *glob* pattern. Regex pattern is `.*_ft_H2O`

Answer (score 0):

While you can do this with a regex, you might simply split the string:

```
units = {"BattV":"volts", …}
for cell in ws[A][1:]:
    project, sensor, unit = cell.value.split("_")
    cell.offset(column=2).value = units[unit]
```